# How to get yesterday data from Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have a `meet` Model in Rails,now I want to get the record yesterday,how should I do?

```
Meet.where(:created_at=> ) # what should I write here?
```

Or ActiveRecord comes with some method to filter the yesterday record?

Comment: What data type is `:created_at`? Does it include time?

Comment: `:created_at` is created by Rails itself through the migrate mark `t.timestamps`.It's type is datetime

Comment: Do you want all records created yesterday or all records that existed as of yesterday (and if so, start or end of yesterday)?

Comment: I just want to get the records created at yesterday(from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Meet.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today-1)
```

Comment: Cool trick. Never seen this syntax, works great for something I needed.

Comment: I'm storing data in the UTC time format (ex: "2017-03-20 00:58:19") and was using the `DATE` method to solve this problem. However, be aware that `DATE` does not convert timezones.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more generic approach, using Arel and scopes:

```
  scope :created_since, (
    lambda do |time|
      where(Meet.arel_table[:created_at].gteq(time))
    end
  )

Meet.created_since(1.day.ago).count
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Rails 5.1 or later you can use `all_day`:

```
Meet.where(created_at: 1.day.ago.all_day)
```

also.. I suggest to define a scope like:

```
scope :yesterday, -> { where(created_at: 1.day.ago.all_day) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Meet.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.yesterday)
```

Comment: thanks,this will return all the records before today,not just yesterday.

Comment: ah my bad. I see you have got the answer. editing mine anyways. Thanks.

Comment: Now this code will return records created exactly at midnight 00:00 yesterday `Meet.where("created_at = ?", DateTime.yesterday)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Meet.find(:all, :conditions => ["DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

By Rails http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

```
Meet.where("created_at < ?", Date.yesterday)
```

or in postgresql

```
Meet.where("created_at < 'yesterday'")
```

Comment: thanks,this will return all the records before today,not just yesterday

Comment: So, you could use just "=" for yesterday records. `Meet.where(created_at: Date.yesterday)` or `Meet.where("created_at = 'yesterday')`

Comment: No,this will not work,if my date is `2013-12-23 05:12:00` the `=` will  return nothing,we must change the `datetime`to `date`(`2013-12-23`) first,then it will work,thanks!